# Dependency Walker with kernel32.dll on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, dependency-walker

I tried to open `kernel32.dll` using Dependency Walker on Windows 10. I got the following error and warning:

> Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found
>
> Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.

Screenshot:
[image: Error reading dependency]

I'm running Windows 10 32-bit, and the Dependency Walker is also 32-bit.
Also, I'm running Dependency Walker as admin.

Comment: If it's any consolation, you're not alone in seeing this error. I get it too. I think it's not a problem as it is caused by a delay-load mechanism which Dependency Walker can't detect. See http://www.dependencywalker.com/faq.html

Comment: @Ash Which version of Dependency Walker are you using? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36049618/234976

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dependency Walker: missing dlls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240215/dependency-walker-missing-dlls)

Answer (score 78):

This has nothing to do with delay loads. These are MS API-sets - [essentially, an extra level of call indirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802935(v=vs.85).aspx) introduced gradually since windows 7. Dependency walker development seemingly halted long before that, and it can't handle API sets properly.

So these are all false negatives and nothing to worry about. You're not missing anything.

[Here it is in more words.](http://ofekshilon.com/2016/03/27/on-api-ms-win-xxxxx-dll-and-other-dependency-walker-glitches/)

---

Edit:  Only in Oct 2017 did someone finally try to fill this gap.  Meet [Dependencies by lucasg](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies). I've only briefly fiddled with it until now, but it handles API sets well and is at least very worthy of attention.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I just moved to windows 10 and Dependencies is working while depends is taking forever.

Comment: This helped me. I had a complex dependency failure that I'd already spent hours trying to resolve using Depends. Dependencies spotted the problem instantly. Much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know if by now there is some similar program available which works on Windows 10?

Comment: @Aziuth I didn't experience any problems with it on windows 10.

Comment: I tried to use dependencies by lucasg... it didn't launch, apparently due to it's own dependency issues.

Comment: @JeffH  try ProcMon to see what is missing

Comment: Thanks, Ofek! I did download procmon, but couldn't figure out how to use it for this purpose.

Comment: @JeffH filter to process name=dependencies.exe, observe file activity before process shutdown. You should be able to quickly see something like a DLL sought after in many locations (the entire PATH) before failing and exiting.   Maybe it's a mismatch in .net version?

Comment: @JeffH so what was it?

Comment: Ofek - can't really tell from the filtered output. It even complains on a machine that the installed app does run on.

Comment: Ofek - I found this tool, ".NET Dependency Walker"  that is much more clear about things: https://www.workshell.co.uk/products/netdepends/

Comment: Yes, .net has a different tool ecosystem. The parallel to Process-Monitor is probably Fusion log (see assembly load during runtime)

Answer (score 18):

There's a reimplementation of dependency walker that is meant to implement for the later features of the dll mechanisms. Have a look at

https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies

Comment: sadly that is a rather feature incomplete replacement with no life profiling support that vastly limits its usability

Comment: I tried dependcy to spot an issue with one of our DLL and it did not spot it. I had to resort to procmon to find the missing DLL. Sad that we do not have a proper replacement of Dependecy Walker.

Comment: This answer doesn't bring anything new (compared to @OfekShilon's),.

Comment: Are there more alternatives? Preferably without dependency on `.net`?