# Circular dependency errors from KERNEL32.DLL?

Tags: windows, kernel32, dependency-walker

Recently I've had a problem that seemingly every DLL I've opened with Dependency Walker gives an error like:

[image]

*(Dependency Walker Module Error - "c:\windows\syswow64\MSVBVM50.DLL" will fail to load due to circular dependencies.)*

I'm using MSVBVM50 as an example, but this happens with loads of other DLLs as well. After clicking OK and letting it open, this is what happens:

[image]

It takes a little while to load, I think eventually it reaches some maximum depth & just stops loading any further (seeing as it doesn't hang/crash).

This circularity roots in `API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-0.DLL` which depends on `KERNEL32.DLL` etc. `KERNEL32` is a core part of Windows... How is this possible / what does it mean? Can I fix it?

Running on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a different symptom of the same underlying problem as this question:

[Dependency Walker with kernel32.dll on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604738/dependency-walker-with-kernel32-dll-on-windows-10)

And as also noted in a comment on the question, Dependency walker is pretty out of date at this point and has fallen behind modern details of Windows.