# 64bit FireDac connection to Interbase requires unnecessary ibtogo64.dll?

Tags: delphi, firedac, interbase, delphi-11-alexandria

After converting my Delphi Alexandria 11.3 program from 32 to 64 bits, I noticed that connecting to a (64bit) FireBird database required other DLLs.

In `FireDac.Phys.IBWrapper` this procedure gets called with

```
AVendorHome=''
AVendorLib=''
ALibNames=('ibclient64.dll', 'ibtogo64.dll')

procedure TIBLib.LoadBase(const AVendorHome, AVendorLib: String; AThreadSafe: Boolean
  {$IFNDEF FireDAC_IB_STATIC} ; const ALibNames: array of String {$ENDIF});
{$IFNDEF FireDAC_IB_STATIC}
var
  sDLLName: String;
  aDLLNames: array of String;
  i, j, n: Integer;
{$ENDIF}
begin
  FThreadSafe := AThreadSafe;
{$IFNDEF FireDAC_IB_STATIC}
  for j := 1 to 2 do begin
    sDLLName := AVendorHome;
    if sDLLName <> '' then begin
      sDLLName := FDNormPath(sDLLName);
      if j = 2 then
        sDLLName := FDNormPath(sDLLName + C_FD_DLLFolder);
    end
    else if j = 2 then
      Break;
    n := Length(aDLLNames);
    if AVendorLib <> '' then begin
      SetLength(aDLLNames, n + 1);
      aDLLNames[n] := sDLLName + AVendorLib;
    end
    else begin
      SetLength(aDLLNames, n + Length(ALibNames));
      for i := 0 to Length(ALibNames) - 1 do            <-- HERE
        aDLLNames[n + i] := sDLLName + ALibNames[i];
    end;
  end;
  inherited Load(aDLLNames, True);
{$ELSE}
  LoadEntries;
  GetLibraryInfo;
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

What this does is filling the initially empty `aDLLNames` with the two entries in `ALibNames` ('HERE')
The inherited `Load(aDLLNames, True)` (the True meaning Required) then tries to load *both* DLLs with `inherited LoadLibrary(ADLLNames, ARequired)`

I copied the two files `ibclient64.dll` and `interbase.msg` from `c:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Interbase\redist\InterBase2020\win64\` to my program directory,
but the above code *also* requires `ibtogo64.dll`, so this then fails on the `ibtogo64.dll` with 'Cannot load vendor library':

[image]

My code does not use IBToGo.

The array with the two names was set up in ('HERE'):

```
procedure TIBLib.LoadIB(const AVendorHome, AVendorLib: String;
  AEmbedded, AThreadSafe: Boolean);
{$IFNDEF FireDAC_IB_STATIC}
const
  C_GDS:      String = {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS} {$IFDEF FireDAC_64} 'ibclient64' {$ELSE} 'gds32' {$ENDIF} {$ENDIF}
                       {$IFDEF POSIX} 'libgds' {$ENDIF} + C_FD_DLLExt;
  C_TOGO:     String = {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS} {$IFDEF FireDAC_64} 'ibtogo64' {$ELSE} 'ibtogo' {$ENDIF} {$ENDIF}
                       {$IFDEF POSIX} 'libibtogo' {$ENDIF} + C_FD_DLLExt;
{$ENDIF}
begin
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  FDSetEnv('INTERBASE', TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'interbase');
{$ENDIF}
  if AEmbedded then
    // Force ToGo
    LoadBase(AVendorHome, AVendorLib, AThreadSafe
{$IFNDEF FireDAC_IB_STATIC},
      [C_TOGO]
{$ENDIF}
    )
  else
    LoadBase(AVendorHome, AVendorLib, AThreadSafe
{$IFNDEF FireDAC_IB_STATIC},
  {$IF DEFINED(MACOS) and not DEFINED(IOS)}
      // MacOSX: InterBase ToGo is preferred, and thus LIBIBTOGO has a higher priority
      [C_TOGO, C_GDS]
  {$ELSEIF DEFINED(IOS) or DEFINED(ANDROID)}
      // iOS, iOSSim, Android: no client/server, and thus no LIBGDS
      [C_TOGO]
  {$ELSE}
      // Windows: client/server is preferred over ToGo
      [C_GDS, C_TOGO]       <-- HERE
  {$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}
  );
end;
```

Isn't that strange? If I have `ibclient64.dll`, why require `ibtogo64.dll`?
Should I report this as a bug?

And the next question is what the best solution is (assuming that `ibtogo64.dll` is indeed not necessary). Distribute `ibtogo64.dll` with my app as well <sup>*</sup>, or hack the code to not include `C_TOGO` in the array?

That conditional define `FireDAC_IB_STATIC` is set in `FireDac.Inc` as:

```
{$IF DEFINED(IOS) and (DEFINED(CPUARM) or DEFINED(CPUARM64)) or DEFINED(ANDROID)}
  {$DEFINE FireDAC_IB_STATIC}            // Use IB driver static linking
  {$DEFINE FireDAC_IB_STATIC_IBBRAND}    // Use IbTogo static linking library
{$ENDIF}
```

Using that define would seem to 'solve' the issue, were it not that the definition of `TIBLib.LoadBase` changes. I'd probably open a can of worms trying to use that.

<sup>* Actually , there are 3 DLLs in `c:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Interbase\redist\InterBase2020\win64_togo\`: `ibtogo64.dll`, `ibxml64.dll` and `ib_util64.dll`</sup>

Comment: LoadLibrary will only try the second entry when the first fails. You should check why it fails.

Comment: @Uwe Ah yes, you are correct, the ibclient64.dll already fails. Strange, it's in the executable directory and the Windows call from System.SysUtils.SafeLoadLibrary is LoadLibrary(Pchar(Filename)) with Filename = 'ibclient64.dll'

Comment: If I move ibclient64.dll to either C;\Windows\System32 or C;\Windows\SysWow64 it still fails. I don't have to register the DLL, do I?

Comment: Did you install vcredist_x64.exe?

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` return when `LoadLibrary()` fails on `ibclient64.dll`?

Comment: @UweRaabe I could not see if that was on my system, so I installed the latest X64 version from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170
This made no difference.

Comment: @RemyLebeau GetLastError returns 126 directly after the LoadLibrary call (that's with ibclient64.dll in the directory of the executable). If I look that up it is
ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND The specified module could not be found. Now trying to get dependency walker installed...

Comment: Dependency Walker (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56275682/512728)) finds a lot of errors. The first one is a missing dependency on MSVCR120.DLL, which is in the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio **2013**, so I installed that one as well.
There were a lot of missing dependencies for API_MS_WIN_... and EXT_MS_WIN_....  DLLS but these are [false alarms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36244483/512728)
The reported missing HVSIFILETRUST.DLL, IESHIMS.DLL and PDMUTILITIES.DLL may also be false alarms

Comment: BUT! After installing the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio **2013** the LoadLibrary call now works, hurrah!

Comment: Next question: should I leave this question open or delete it? This comment thread can be useful to others, but ion the question body I was initially looking in the wrong direction (overlooking that the error was already with the first DLL).

Comment: @JanDoggen that is up to you. I would suggest [posting your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) detailing the solution you discovered.